# Libcurl, cef browser conflict on ssl request

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, openssl, chromium-embedded

I have application, which uses libcurl for network connection and libcef for rendering html.

Everything works fine, except one issue: if libcurl  is used after libcef is initialized, https requests will take significant amount of time(more than one second).

Here is minimal code, which illustrates the problem:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "include/cef_app.h"

class MyCefApp: public CefApp
{
private:
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(MyCefApp);
};

int main()
{
    CefMainArgs main_args;
    CefRefPtr<CefApp> App = new MyCefApp();
    CefExecuteProcess(main_args, App, NULL);
    CefSettings settings;
    CefInitialize(main_args, settings, App, NULL);


    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    double val;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME, &val);
    std::cout<<"CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME: "<<val<<"  sec.";

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


  return 0;
}
```

Application output will be like:

*CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME: 1.29  sec.*

But when line

```
CefInitialize(main_args, settings, App, NULL);
```

will be commented, or curl block will be placed before cef block, output will be like:

*CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME: 0.38  sec.*

If I use non ssl version of google, problem disapears.

I use:

```
libcurl/7.48.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1s zlib/1.2.8
```

Libcurl built with

```
mode=dll VC=14 WITH_SSL=dll WITH_ZLIB=dll ENABLE_SSPI=no ENABLE_IPV6=yes ENABLE_IDN=no ENABLE_WINSSL=no GEN_PDB=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x86
```

libcurl, openssl, zlib and libcef build with VS 2015 community eddition, on Windows 7.

Could anyone point me, why ssl requests behaves like that?
Thanks.